# Android Firebase check if added child value is in concrete range from database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in using firebase, try to find best solution for my case.

I want to implement some highscore system, which will check if the user's score is in the top scores, e.g between top 10 scores in actual database.

My database structure is like this:

```
Score
  -KdqwHzp2mFEPEEbTylu
      nickname: "jackson"
      result: 20
  -KdqwYBJUGi-dsDak56n
      nickname: "jackson"
      result: 13
  -Kdr--la-ZCcKkurE1Bl
      nickname:"jackson"
      result: 15
```

And my Score object:

```
public class Score {
    private String nickname;
    private Integer result;

    public Score(String nickname, Integer result) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
        this.result = result;
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname = nickname;
    }

    public Integer getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(Integer result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Anyone can give me an advice how to implement this and give sample of code?

Answer (score 0):

You'd use a query for that:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().ref("Score");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("result").limitToLast(10);
query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot scoreSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Score score = scoreSnapshot.getValue(Score.class);
            ...
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // Getting Post failed, log a message
        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        // ...
    }
});
```

Note that the scores will be in increasing order. The Firebase Database does not have an operator to return a descending list. So if you want to show a leaderboard, you'll have to reverse them on the client.